# Home Brewing in South Africa

Tags: laws

If I brew beer at home can I give it to friends or relatives. In South Africa

Comment: You might want to try asking this on the Law SE since I assume you're asking about the legality

Comment: Does this help: [brewing - How to homebrew legally in South Africa? - Beer, Wine & Spirits Stack Exchange](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/how-to-homebrew-legally-in-south-africa)

Comment: Yes, you can give home-brewed beer to and share it with anyone you like. You simply cannot sell it - at least not without the proper license.